# Error instalar xampp en linux

Tags: linux, xampp

Después de ejecutar:

```
sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-7.2.26-0-installer.run
```

Me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error.

```
./xampp-linux-x64-7.2.26-0-installer.run: 1: ./xampp-linux-x64-7.2.26-0-installer.run: ELF: not found
./xampp-linux-x64-7.2.26-0-installer.run: 2: ./xampp-linux-x64-7.2.26-0-installer.run: 
@@@0@00088@8@00ý®#ý®#°#°c°¾øÔ ë# ëc ëcÐÐTT@T@: not found
./xampp-linux-x64-7.2.26-0-installer.run: 6: ./xampp-linux-x64-7.2.26-0-installer.run: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

Gracias

P.D.: El archivo cuenta con permisos de ejecución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primera que arquitectura tenes 64 o 32 bits Xampp solo esta para 64 bits, podes saber la arquitectura con un simple comando en el prompt@: arch también tenes que ser más especifico respeto a que sistema operativo tenes. Yo nunca tuve problemas con Xampp emm trata de ejecutarlo como root. sudo su y luego ./xampp-linux-x64-7.2.26-0-installer.run

Answer (score 0):

¡Buenas @Gaby!

Ese error es común cuando intentas instalar Xampp en un sistema de 32Bits. Ya que como menciona @Matias Javier, solo existe versión de 64 bits.

[Aquí puedes encontrar el error en el formo de la pagina oficial.](https://community.apachefriends.org/viewtopic.php?p=238800)

No hay una solución cómoda para este problema. Si tu ordenador lo permite, instala un Sistema Operativo de 64 bits.

¡Un saludo!